# PHP - 2 variables in 1 string

Tags: php

```
$title = get_the_title(); 
echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=\"" .$title. "\"" : "") ?
```

This code sets my field value text as the contents of the `$title` variable. I have another variable `$refcode` which I would like to sit next to the title so it would read something like:

Title [refcode]

I am just not sure how I place my new variable next to title?

Comment: Be sure to call `htmlspecialchars($title, ENT_QUOTES)` on that before inserting it into a `value=''` attribute. Any internal quotes in the title will break your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `sprintf` for a better overview on you string.

```
$title = get_the_title();
$recode = 123;

echo ($field['field_name'] == 'Subject'
  ? sprintf( ' value="%s" refcode="%d" ', $title, $recode )
  : '');
```

You can add as many placeholder (`%s, %d`) as you want – the order of the given parameters matter.
For further description see: http://php.net/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
 echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=\"" .$title. " [" . $refcode . "]\"" : "")
```

You can see demo here: **[codepad](http://codepad.org/O1tb1n7b)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a short if/else, just do a elseif:

```
    if( isset($someVariable) ){ $echoString = $someVariable; }
elseif( isset($someOtherVariable) ){ $echoString = $someOtherVariable; }
else{ $echoString = "default Value";

echo $echoString;
```

---

A small tip: If working with html, use single quotes. You dont have to escape the double-quotes:

```
// double quotes
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"example\" class=\"someClass\" />";
// single quotes (IMO better to read)
echo '<input type="text" value="example" class="someClass" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=\"$title\" [ \"$refcode ]\" ": "")
```

You can use variables directly inside double quotes.

Since your sample output does not contain quotes, you might use it like this.

```
echo ($field["field_name"] == "Subject" ? "value=$title[$refcode]": "")
```